# Evaluating this integral $ \small\int \frac {x^2 dx} {(x\sin x+\cos x)^2} $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The question:

> Compute$$
> \int \frac {x^2 \, \operatorname{d}\!x} {(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}
> $$

Tried integration by parts. That didn't work.

How do I proceed?

Comment: What makes you think that it has an anti-derivative?

Comment: Well, it is there in the problem sheet that we are working at. (Btw, what makes you think it DOESN'T have an anti-derivative?)

Comment: @ParthThakkar: Given a random function, it most likely does not have an anti-derivative in terms of elementary functions. of course, if you tell the source, one would not have had to ask you this question.

Comment: Ok, got it! Now onwards, such things will be mentioned if required.

Comment: @Vijay: Now I suspect there is a typo. Are you sure the denominator is not $(x \sin x + \cos x)^2$? (In which case lab's answer would be perfect).

Comment: Yes, sorry for the error. Editing. (also scolding Vijay for this XD)

Comment: @ParthThakkar, lol, I'm somewhat sure that i posted the right question

Comment: @VijayRaghavan: my apologies if this caused an error, there is yet no mechanisms to lock things when people are working on them and when I was trying to review and fix the edits, things seemed to have gone astray. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti....... np

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$$\text{Observe that, }\frac{d(x\sin x+\cos x)}{dx}=x\cos x$$

$$ \int \frac {x^2 \, \operatorname{d}\!x} {(x\sin x+\cos x)^2} =\int \frac x{\cos x}\cdot \frac{x\cos x}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx$$

So, if $z=x\sin x+\cos x, dz=x\cos xdx$

So, $\int \frac{x\cos x}{(x\sin x+\sin x)^2}dx=\int \frac{dz}{z^2}=-\frac1z=-\frac1{x\sin x+\cos x}$

So, $$I=\frac x{\cos x}\int \frac{x\cos x}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx-\int \left(\frac{d(\frac x{\cos x})}{dx}\int \frac{x\cos x}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx\right)dx$$

$$=-\frac x{\cos x(x\sin x+\cos x)}+\int \left(\frac{x\sin x+\cos x}{\cos^2x}\right)\left(\frac1{x\sin x+\cos x} \right)dx$$

$$=-\frac x{\cos x(x\sin x+\cos x)}+\int\sec^2xdx$$

$$=-\frac x{\cos x(x\sin x+\cos x)}+\tan x+C$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant of indefinite integral

$$\text{Another form will be  } \frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x+\cos x}+C$$

Comment: Damn! We had observed the derivative thingy, but couldn't think of multiplying and diving by $cos x$. Smart!

Comment: Thanks.. Got the solution.

Comment: @VijayRaghavan, my pleasure.

Comment: @Aryabhata, is it ok now?

Comment: Same here can't understand :(

Comment: @Aryabhata, let me rectify, misread the Question. Thanks for your input

Comment: What?????????? It was a bigggggg mistake. Haha . Even the answer was accepted and 3 up-votes. @VijayRaghavan and others all trolled..... `:D`

Comment: @exploringnet, if it was big enough, how it eluded both the acceptor & the solver?

Comment: Aah! now the question is edited.

Comment: How can you take the $x/\cos x$ out of the integral?????

Comment: @martycohen, I have used Integration by Parts(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), $$\int u(x)v'(x) dx=u(x)v(x)-\int[u'(x)v(x)]dx$$ Setting $v'(x)=w(x)\implies v(x)=\int w(x)dx$ to find $$\int u(x)w(x)dx=u(x)\int w(x)dx-\int[u'(x)\cdot\int w(x)dx]dx$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee what is u and v here

Comment: @labbhattacharjee can you help me in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857096/298843

Answer (score 17):

Differentiation of $$x\sin x+\cos x \space \text {is}\space  x\cos x $$
\begin{align}\int\underbrace {\frac{x \cos x}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}}_{\text {II}}\cdot\underbrace {\frac {x}{(\cos x)}}_{\text {I}}{d}x\end{align}
Now integrate by parts. 
$$I=\frac{-1}{(x\sin x+\cos x)}.\frac {x}{(\cos x)} +\int\frac{1}{(x\sin x+\cos x)}.\frac{\cos x.1 -x(-\sin x)}{\cos^2 x} $$
Now, I hope things are clear to you.

Comment: Will it not be too long

Comment: @koolman No.., Give it a try .

Comment: in first step will we take $d(xsin x + cos x)$

Comment: @koolman Yes..${}{}{}{}$

Comment: then it will be tooo long.....

Comment: I think you have a typo: $\cos x\cdot 1-x (-\sin x) $ as numerator of the second fraction in the last integrand.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Thanks ..

Answer (score 16):

I was inspired [by this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698591/evaluation-of-int-frac1x22x2x-cos-x-sin-x4dx) to conduct this method.

$$\int\frac{x^2}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}\mathrm{d}x $$

The [Harmonic Addition Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicAdditionTheorem.html) comes in handy, so $x \sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{1+x^2} \cos(x-\alpha)$ where $\alpha = \arctan(x)$.

The origin integration becomes:

$$\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \sec^2(x-\alpha) \mathrm{d}x  $$

Notice that $\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} dx = x - \arctan x = x-\alpha $.

So let $t = x-\alpha$ then $dt = \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} dx$ and the integration simplifies as:

$$ \int \sec^2(t) dt = \tan(t) = \tan(x - \arctan x)$$.

In conclusion, $$\int\frac{x^2}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}\mathrm{d}x =\tan(x - \arctan x)+C$$

Comment: Is that $a = \arctan(x)$ meant to be $\alpha = \arctan(x)$?

Comment: @someonewithpc Yes a typo.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{x^2}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}\mathrm{d}x = \int (x\sec x)\frac{x \cos x}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
Take $xsecx$ as first functions and apply integreation by parts. there you go boom!!