# Beautiful Indefinite Integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, indefinite-integrals

These are some of the integrals with beautiful solutions I came across-

$$\int \frac{x^2}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2} dx$$

$$\int\frac {1}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x} dx$$

$$\int \frac{1}{x^4+1}dx$$

I'd love if you share some of the ones you came across.

Comment: Define "beautiful".

Comment: I know perception of beauty is subjective, but what do you see as beautiful about the solution of the third integral, for example?

Comment: @mirgee actually, second one integrates pretty ugly too.

Comment: I've always been very fond of the integrals of $\sec{x}$ and $\sec^3{x}$.

Comment: @Kaster: The graph is pretty though... :)

Comment: I believe this should be a community wiki though...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals

Comment: Here is a link that goes thorugh the evalutation of some pretty tough indefinite integrals. http://www-sop.inria.fr/cafe/Manuel.Bronstein/publications/issac98.pdf

Comment: @Mirgee- Breaking the numerator into $\frac{x^2+1-(x^2-1)}{2}$ in the third is quite neat trick to me.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403167/find-the-value-of-int-frac-x2x-sin-x-cos-x2-dx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
I_1 & = \int \sqrt{ \sqrt{ x + 2\sqrt{2x-4} } + 
                       \sqrt{ x - 2\sqrt{2x-4} } } \,\mathrm{d}x \, , \quad x>4\\
I_2 & = \int \log( \log x) + \frac{2}{\log x}  - \frac{1}{(\log x)^2} \mathrm{d}x \\
I_4 & = \int (1 + 2x^2) e^{x^2}\,  \mathrm{d}x \\ 
I_5 & = \int \frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1\,}\,}\,}{\sqrt{x^2+1\,}\,}  \mathrm{d}x \\
I_6 & = \int \frac{2^x 3^x}{9^x - 4^x} \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
    I_7 
         = \int \left( \frac{\arctan x}{x - \arctan x}\right)^2 \mathrm{d}x
         = \frac{1 + x \arctan x}{\arctan x - x} 
  = \frac{1}{\tan (\beta - \tan \beta)}\,,
\end{align*}
where $x = \tan \tan \beta$ or $\beta = \arctan (\arctan x)$.
$$
I_6 = \int \frac{x^2+2x+1+ (3x+1)\sqrt{x+\ln x}}{x\,\sqrt{x+\ln x}(x+\sqrt{x+\ln x})}\mathrm{d}x
= 2 (\sqrt{x+\ln x} + \ln(x+\sqrt{x+\ln x})) + C
$$
I have a bunch more of these [here](http://folk.ntnu.no/oistes/Diverse/Integral%20Kokeboken.pdf), see p.68 for instance. (click on the problems for solution)

Comment: awesome work, thank you for posting this!

Comment: The link seems to be dead, where can I get the solutions of these?

Answer (score 8):

This isn't indefinite. But it's crazy

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{ d \theta}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2 \sin^2\theta }} = \frac{\pi}{2AGM(a,b)} $$

Where AGM is the arithmetic geometric mean.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int\dfrac{x^{4n}(1+x^{4n})}{1+x^2}dx$$

Why? Because from $0$ to $1$ they give good approximations of $\pi$. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80)

Comment: cleverly constructed!! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

$$\int (\sqrt {\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x})dx=\sqrt 2\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}}{\sqrt 2} +C$$

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram alpha gives time exceeded on this one :

$$\int\dfrac{(x-1)\sqrt{x^4+2x^3-x^2+2x+1}}{x^2(x+1)}dx=\sqrt{t^2+2t-3}-\ln{(t+1+\sqrt{t^2+2t-3})}+\sqrt 3 \arcsin{\dfrac{t+5}{2(t+2)}}+C$$

where $t=x+\dfrac 1 x$

One does not simply integrate this.

Comment: I don't understand the reason of the downvote. '+1'

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \left| \sin{ax} \right|\,dx = {2 \over a} \left\lfloor \frac{ax}{\pi} \right\rfloor - {1 \over a} \cos{\left( ax - \left\lfloor \frac{ax}{\pi} \right\rfloor \pi \right)} + C$$

$$\int \left|\cos {ax}\right|\,dx = {2 \over a} \left\lfloor \frac{ax}{\pi} + \frac12 \right\rfloor + {1 \over a} \sin{\left( ax - \left\lfloor \frac{ax}{\pi} + \frac12 \right\rfloor \pi \right)} + C$$

Answer (score 2):

The [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) isn't indefinite but its derivation and answer are still remarkable:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$