# Find $\int\frac{(ax^2-b)}{x\sqrt{c^2x^2-(ax^2+b)^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to find $$\int\frac{(ax^2-b)}{x\sqrt{c^2x^2-(ax^2+b)^2}}dx$$ ?

Usually in such cases I use the substitution $x=1/t$ but here it doesn't seem to work.Any hints or ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could show the start of your solution? If you tried the substitution, then show where you are stuck. Otherwise, it looks like you are going through your homework and posting it here with little effort on your part

Comment: Okay.Give me some time please.I'm editing.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$I =\int\frac{(ax^2-b)}{x\sqrt{c^2x^2-(ax^2+b)^2}}dx = \int\frac{ax^2-b}{x\cdot x \sqrt{c^2-(ax+\frac{b}{x})^2}}dx$$

So $$I = \int\frac{a-\frac{b}{x^2}}{\sqrt{c^2-(ax+\frac{b}{x})^2}}dx$$

Now Put $\left(ax+\frac{b}{x}\right) = t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \left(a-\frac{b}{x^2}\right)dx = dt$

So $$I = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-t^2}}dt = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{t}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = \int\frac{(ax^2-b)}{x\sqrt{c^2x^2-(ax^2+b)^2}}dx=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{cx}{ax^2+b}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: Makes sense, because of the symmetry +1

Comment: good one (+1) !

Comment: I meant that the substitutions $u=x^2$ and $v=1/x^2$ just exchange $a$ and $b$. $$\int \frac{(au-b)}{u\sqrt{c^2u-(au+b)^2}}du=\int \frac{(bv-a)}{v\sqrt{c^2v-(bv+a)^2}}dv$$