# Number of tangents

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Why there is no points where tangent does not exist for the curve y =sgn($x^2$$-1$)

As there are breaks in its graph so I think there should be three points where it is discontinous but it is not so why

How we will get vertical tangent can you show me mathematically and graphically

Comment: Does $\mathrm{sgn}$ mean "sign"?

Comment: @jamesh625 sgn is signum function

Comment: "Why there is no points where tangent does not exist for the curve $y =sgn(x^2−1)$" -- What makes you think that this is true?  y has a jump discontinuity at two places, the derivative does not exist,  and there is no tangent.  If this were physics class and not math class, you can draw a vertical line connecting the dots, because physicists don't care about so much about rigor.

Comment: @DougM but according to me for a tangent to exist it is not necessary to be continous but it is necessary to be continous for it to be differentiable.

Comment: can anyone tell me if I am correct

Answer (score 0):

There are TWO points where it is discontinuous (not three): -1, +1.  At each of these points the value of the function is zero.  And in the immediate neighborhood of each, there are points on one side where the value of the function is +1, and on the other side where the value of the function is -1.  If you try to infer the slope of a tangent line through either point, as the limit of the slopes of secants through either point, you get a vertical line in each case; however, for any point near either of these, the slope of the tangent at that point is obviously zero (horizontal lines).  Since the limit of 'horizontal' as you approach either point is 'horizontal', but the expected slope is 'vertical', then properly speaking no tangent exists.  [I think]  Certainly no DERIVATIVE exists.