# Method of integration

Tags: integration, combinatorics, definite-integrals

We have to find the integration of the following function[image: tt]

I tried but got stuck can anybody help me how to proceed . Is there anyother method to solve this [image]

Comment: Is that$$\int\frac{n^2}{\left(n\sin n+\cos n\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}n~~?$$Or is there a mix of $n$'s and $x$'s?

Comment: Have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366509/evaluating-this-integral-small-int-frac-x2-dx-x-sin-x-cos-x2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @user170231 in my question there no n only 'x' is present

Comment: [lab bhattacharjee](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366509/evaluating-this-integral-small-int-frac-x2-dx-x-sin-x-cos-x2) answer is a nice way of working out this integral.

Comment: @JanEerland i want to know how to proceed through my method

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858507/method-of-integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

$\int \dfrac {x^2}{(x \sin x + \cos x)^2} dx\\
\int (x \sec x)\dfrac {x \cos x}{(x \sin x + \cos x)^2} dx$

How about integration by parts?

$u = x \sec x\\
dv \frac {x \cos x}{(x \sin x + \cos x)^2} dx$

Comment: Can you tell me how to proceed by my method

Comment: Otherwise this method is best upvote

Comment: Your integral at the end.  Multiply top and bottom by $\cos^2 x.$  Stuff cancels.  Then you have a rather simple $\int sec^2 x dx$

Comment: can you help me in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857096/298843