# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x\arctan(x)}\right)^2dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate this integral?
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x\arctan(x)}\right)^2\mathrm dx$$

$y=\arctan(x)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(y)}$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{y^2(1+\tan^2(y))}{(1+y\tan(y))^2}\mathrm dy$$

This looked transformation is far harder than the original one.

I checked on Wolfram integral, it returns a nice closed form of $\frac{4-\pi}{4+\pi}$ apparently. Is this result correct?

Comment: $$\int{{{\left( \frac{{{\tan }^{-1}}\left( x \right)}{1+x{{\tan }^{-1}}\left( x \right)} \right)}^{2}}dx}=\frac{x-{{\tan }^{-1}}\left( x \right)}{x{{\tan }^{-1}}\left( x \right)+1}+C$$

Comment: Computer algebra gives:  $\frac{4-\pi }{4+\pi }$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Multiply numerator and denominator by $\cos^2y$ to find

$$\int\dfrac{y^2}{(\cos y+y\sin y)^2}dy$$

Now as $\dfrac{d(\cos y+y\sin y)}{dy}=y\cos y$

write $\dfrac{y^2}{(...)^2}=\dfrac{y\cos y}{(...)^2}\cdot y\sec y$

Now integrate by part

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366509/evaluating-this-integral-small-int-frac-x2-dx-x-sin-x-cos-x2/366523#366523