# Find the value of $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left({\frac{x}{x\sin x+\cos x}}\right)^2dx$

Tags: integration

Find the value of $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left({\frac{x}{x\sin x+\cos x}}\right)^2dx$

My approach is as follow $(x\sin x+\cos x)^{-1}=t$

$$-\frac{x\cos x}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx=dt$$

After this steps I am not able to approach it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366509/evaluating-this-integral-small-int-frac-x2-dx-x-sin-x-cos-x2

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\sin$ and $\cos$ using `\sin` and `\cos`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly relevant for legibility if you mix fractions and exponents. More generally, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$I(x)=\int \frac{x^2 dx}{(x\sin +\cos x)^2}= \int x \sec x  \frac{(x \cos x)}{(x \sin x+\cos )^2} dx$$. Let us integrate by parts, and taking $(x\sin x+\cos x)=t$. We get
$$I(x)=-x \sec x  (x\sin x+\cos x)^{-1} +\int \frac{(\sec x +x\sec x \tan x)}{(x\sin x+\cos x)} dx=$$
$$I(x)=-x \sec x  (x\sin x+\cos x)^{-1}+ \int \sec^2 x ~dx$$
$$I(x)=-x \sec x  (x\sin x+\cos x)^{-1}+ \tan x+C$$
So the required definite integral in $(0, \pi/4)$ is $$I=\frac{4-\pi}{4+\pi}$$